# IE and Socket.io compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, node.js, socket.io, opera

I make some chat example like here: http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/

When I use Chrome and Firefox everything works like a charm. With IE9 or Opera some socket.io events are not firing (e.g. disconnect) or firing too late, and data receiving is too slow.

I installed node.js and socket.io module with the npm method.

Please help.

Answer (score 9):

Socket.IO works best with websockets.  Prior to 2012, most browsers did not support websockets ([source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)).

With such browsers, socket.io falls back to various polling methods, but those may lead to problems you are experiencing, such as low data rate and delayed events (firing 1-2 minutes late). To remedy, this you should try to enable flash sockets.

```
 io.set('transports', [
     'websocket'
   , 'flashsocket'
   , 'htmlfile'
   , 'xhr-polling'
   , 'jsonp-polling'
 ]);
```

Also, make sure the flash policy port (default 10843) is reachable from the client.

Comment: `htmlfile` is an ActiveX way for IE

Comment: When I try this, the `io` object doesn't have a '`set`' method. This is client side, after including `socket.io.js`

Comment: Thanks for this Martin, resolved my issue with IE9 causing a read error ECONNRESET on clicking Refresh. Now it fires the disconnect correctly and immediately kills my user.
Khior - I did this in my server side file, directly after requiring socket.io

Comment: Minor edit:  Most pre-2012 browsers did not support WebSockets, not just Opera.  The first support came in IE 10 (9/2012), Firefox 11 (1/2012), Chrome 16 (10/2011), Safari 7 (10/2013), Opera 12 (11/2012), iOS 6 (1/2013), Android 4.4 (12/2013).  Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets