# is it possible to using socket.io-client under IE 9?

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, browser, websocket, socket.io

is it possible to using socket.io-client under IE 9?

i implement chatting server by `NodeJS` with `Socket.IO`.

and implement chatting front-end by standard javascript.

im using `Sockket.IO` version 1.4.5.

this is my client-side code

```
var connectionOptions =  {
    "forceNew" : true,
    "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity",
    "timeout" : 10000,.
    "transports" : ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'],
    'autoConnect': true
};

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', connectionOptions);

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log(1);
});

socket.on('message', function(data) {

});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {

});
```

on chrome and ie 10(and above version), it works well and console logging 1.

but on ie 9, it doesnt work. and network tracking request is not transmitted.

anybody help me plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 does not support webSockets which socket.io works best with.  socket.io will detect that webSockets are not supported and will attempt to use one of the other transports (most likely xhr polling) which can work but may have some compromised behavior.   With xhr polling, there is not as reliable a "connect" and "disconnect" event (since there is no persistent connection) so you should try just sending a message to see if that works for you.

Other related answers:

[IE and Socket.io compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993704/ie-and-socket-io-compatibility)

[Will IE9 now be supporting WebSocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294340/will-ie9-now-be-supporting-websocket)